# Javascript/CSS Rollover menu

Tags: javascript, css, rollover

A past client of mine contacted me about doing a rollover menu for his website.
He has a couple different businesses, and from his main site he wants to be able to have a image menu that shows each of his other businesses and links to their sites.
I know that it is possible to do a rollover menu using javascript and css but one thing he asked me about I'm not sure.  To quote him:

> I basically just want the one that is hovered over to be bigger and lit up. I think it would be neat if they would spin like a conveyor belt. For example... if I had 10 businesses but only 5 show on the page..then as the person moves there mouse over or clicks an "over button" then it would reveal the next business graphics in line.

Is that doable?  Is it a huge project to do something like that?  How could I do that exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a carousel. There are [plenty of them out there](http://www.queness.com/post/711/15-attractive-javascript-carousel-plugins).

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to work with Flash, there are several ready-made tools that can get this done for you. For example, something like this:

http://www.flashloaded.com/flashcomponents/3dstack/

If that isn't exactly what you're looking for, they also offer several other tools with similar functionality.

This may be closer to what you're looking for:

http://www.flashloaded.com/flashcomponents/photoflow/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but is this the type of menu he's talking about? I got lost in the description a little, but this menu will expand items as you hover and uses jquery/javascript:

http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/

Comment: I've worked with jqDock before and that was what I was going to go with, but I think the carousel ones are more what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) to do this.